# calculating for mean square displacement

Tags: matlab

```
clear all; close all; clc;

figure(1)
set(gcf,'Units','normalized','Position',[0 0 1 1])

N = 100;
M = 100;
x(1,M) = 0;
y(1,M) = 0;

for n = 2:1:N

     bx = randi([0,1],1,M)*2-1; % binary random number
     by = randi([0,1],1,M)*2-1; % binary random number

     x(n,:) = x(n-1,:) + bx;
     y(n,:) = y(n-1,:) + by;

     subplot(1,2,1)
     plot(x(:,1),y(:,1),'k')
     xlabel('x')
     ylabel('y')
     axis equal
     set(gca,'FontSize',20)

     subplot(3,2,6)
     plot([0:1:n],sqrt(2*[0:1:n]),'r')
     hold on
     plot(sqrt(mean(x.^2+y.^2,2)),'k')
     xlim([0 N])
     xlabel('t')
     ylabel('MSD(t)')
     set(gca,'FontSize',12)

 drawnow()

 end

 msd = mean(sqrt(2*[0;1;n]));
 disp(msd);

 msds = mean(sqrt(mean((x.^2+y.^2),2)));
 disp(msds);
```

------ i have tried running and modified the codes above, and fortunately, it was very successful ... its just that the values that will be displayed on "msd" and "msds" have a very large difference .. the values of both must be closer or almost equal .. well, the command i used for calculating both has been successful for the same simulation but its in one-dimensional .. and the above code is two dimensional ..  what must i do ??

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo at line 39. Try:

```
 msd = mean(sqrt(2*[0:1:n]));
```

instead of:

```
 msd = mean(sqrt(2*[0;1;n]));
```

Then I have the same value for msd and msds.